# property frame not found on object of type _strong id

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

It is my first app that I am trying to build in IOS and I have some problems. Although I have read similar threads here I was not able to find the answer.I want to show popoverview controller on my button click.but unable to do. i am getting error mention in question title above below are my files

.h file

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIPopoverController *popOver;
@property (nonatomic,strong) SecondViewController *popOverView;
```

.m file

```
- (IBAction)Getcompany:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *popoverview=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popover"];
    self.popOver =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverview];
    [self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame  inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];// m getting an error in this line
}
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: i had shown and getting error in third line. on sender.frame

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that `sender` is, in fact, a `UIButton`:

```
- (IBAction)Getcompany:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    SecondViewController *popoverview=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popover"];
    self.popOver =[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverview];
    [self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame  inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
}
```

-or-

you can use the form:

```
[sender frame]
```

rather than:

```
sender.frame
```

NOTE: the name `Getcompany` is not conventional for an Objective-C method; I don't know what it does, but if it's an action method, then something like this is probably better:

```
- (IBAction)companyButtonPressed:(id)sender
```

(note lowercase starting letter and camel-case formatting).

Comment: its worked but now the following exception came  '-Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'
'

Comment: @MishalAwan Ask as new question, otherwise we could go on forever.  Also if this question helped you then upvote and accept it.